# How do you convert a Razor view to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to use my Razor view as some kind of template for sending emails,
so I would like to "save" my template in a view, read it into controller as a string, do some necessary replacements, and then send it.

I have solution that works: my template is hosted somewhere as an HTML page, but I would like to put it into my application (i.e. in my view). I don't know how to read a view as a string in my controller.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use the following. Put it on your base controller if you have one, that way you can access it in all controllers.

```
public static string RenderPartialToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: wrote something very similar recently. pain in a$$

Comment: @DaveA Hehe yeah, it's a pain really, should be easier.

Comment: How can I do the same with .NET CORE?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) library, which does exactly what you want. I've used it before for email templates, and it works great.

You can just do something like this:

```
// Read in your template from anywhere (database, file system, etc.)
var bodyTemplate = GetEmailBodyTemplate();

// Substitute variables using Razor
var model = new { Name = "John Doe", OtherVar = "Hello!" };
var emailBody = Razor.Parse(bodytemplate, model);

// Send email
SendEmail(address, emailBody);
```

Comment: This is useful, but I have some code already written which I don't want to change. I would like only to save my template(html) in view, and literally read html from view as string, and do replacements in controller.

Comment: Understood. I've done what you're doing in the past. However, once I discovered the RazorEngine library, I've found it not only makes developing template parsing a lot easier, but it makes it much simpler to maintain your templates. You can store the templates in a database or somewhere that you can edit them without editing code.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar by using the `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor`? Just looking to solve the problem within Microsoft so that I don't have to justify another depdendency.